# Hide body until it finishes loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload

I created this code so my page would be hidden until it finishes loading. But my code doesn't work as I expected. I expected this to hide the `BODY` until the `OnLoad` event was triggered.
However, instead, it just stays hidden.

Any help would be appreciated, if there is maybe another, better method of hiding the `BODY` until it finishes loading, or what's wrong with this one.

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
function unveil() {
  var thebod = document.getElementById("testbody");
  thebod.STYLE = "display: block;"
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>HELLO</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY ID="testbody" ONLOAD="unveil();" STYLE="display: none;">
  <div align="CENTER">
    HELLO WORLD!
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: try to use a class, and after loaded, remove the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event of the `window` object can do this. But, don't hide the body, hide a wrapper instead. And, when you set the style, make sure to set the style of a CSS property, not the style object itself.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#wrapper { text-align:center; background:#e0e0e0; display:none;}
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>HELLO</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id="wrapper">
    HELLO WORLD!
    
    <!-- The following is only added to create a delay in the 
         parsing of the document -->
    <script>
      for(var i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i){ var x = i / 3.14; }
    </script>  
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the elements 'style' correctly:

You can either do:

```
element.style.display = "block";
```

Or

```
element.setAttribute('style', "display: block");
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function unveil() {
  var thebod = document.getElementById("testbody");
  thebod.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>HELLO</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY ID="testbody" ONLOAD="unveil();" STYLE="display: none;">
  <div align="CENTER">
    HELLO WORLD!
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
thebod.STYLE = "display: block;"
```

which should read:

```
thebod.style.display = 'block';
```

Here is the complete approach (using unobtrusive javascript):

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

function unveil() {
    body.style.display = 'block';
}

window.addEventListener('load', unveil, false);
```

```css
body {
display: none;
}

div {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>HELLO WORLD!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>HELLO</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY ID="testbody" onload="testbody.style.display = '';" style="display: none;">
  <div align="CENTER">
    HELLO WORLD!
  </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```